# Error al iniciar mysql Xampp

Tags: xampp

Tengo un error al iniciar el servicio de xampp, antes funcionaba correctamente en la descripción del panel esta el error que me da.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
este es el log que me genera

```
2019-06-06 18:08:12 d9c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x208b)

2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2019-06-06 18:08:12 3484 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Creo que lo mejor será reinstalarlo y poner una versión reciente. La que estás manejando es de 2015.

Comment: haciendo esto no perdere mis BD anteriores?

Comment: puede tomar respaldo o hacer un backup desde phpmyadmin antes de desintalar

Comment: no se puede realizar respaldo debido a que ya no puedo hacer conexion con mysql